# PyQt5 работа с классом QAction

Tags: python, pyqt5

Есть меню. В меню находятся действия (первый файл).
Нужно сделать так при выборе одного действия в меню (там три их: искать всё; искать телефонные номера;
электронные почты и акк) искалось только то что указано в действие (функция поиска находится во втором файле). Буду благодарен

первый файл

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import window_1
import sys


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, action_search_options_1 = None, action_search_options_2 = None, 
                action_search_options_3 = None):

        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        # берём из функции create_menuBar QAction для работы с файлом window_1
        self.action_search_options_1 = action_search_options_1
        self.action_search_options_2 = action_search_options_2
        self.action_search_options_3 = action_search_options_3


        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget() # создаём центральный виджет
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)

        # settings
        self.setFixedSize(640, 540)
        self.setWindowTitle(" B U G ")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("bug.ico"))

        # делаем сборку
        self.widget_main = self.create_page()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.widget_main)
        self.create_menuBar()
        self.create_toolBar()

    def create_page(self):

        self.widget_page = QtWidgets.QWidget()

        # создание обьектов
        self.button_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Перейти к поиску телефонных\nномеров и электронных почт")

        self.formbox = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        # добавление в box и в окно
        self.formbox.addWidget(self.button_1)

        self.formbox.setSpacing(20)

        self.widget_page.setLayout(self.formbox)

        # датчики и события
        self.button_1.clicked.connect(self.clicked_button_1)

        # сделать главным комонентом в общем
        return self.widget_page  # возращает

    def create_menuBar(self):

        # создание панели-меню и строки состоянии
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenuBar()
        self.status_1 = QtWidgets.QStatusBar()

        self.setStatusBar(self.status_1)
        self.status_1.showMessage("Добро пожаловать!", msecs = 5000)

        # создание категорий меню и функционал в ней
        self.sub_menu_options = QtWidgets.QMenu("Опции")
        self.sub_menu_view = QtWidgets.QMenu('Вид')
        self.sub_menu_help = QtWidgets.QMenu("Справка")

        self.sub_menu_in_options_settings_1 = QtWidgets.QMenu("Настройки")
        self.sub_menu_options_search = QtWidgets.QMenu("Настройки поиска")
        self.sub_menu_in_options_settings_3 = QtWidgets.QMenu("Настройки генерации")

        # настройки строки состояния
        self.options_settings_status = QtWidgets.QAction("Включить панель состояния")
        self.options_settings_status.setCheckable(True)
        self.options_settings_status.setChecked(True)

        self.sub_menu_in_options_settings_1.addAction(self.options_settings_status)
        self.sub_menu_options.addMenu(self.sub_menu_in_options_settings_1)

        # настройки поиска
        self.action_search_options_1 = QtWidgets.QAction("Искать всё")
        self.action_search_options_1.setCheckable(True)
        self.action_search_options_1.setChecked(True)
        self.action_search_options_2 = QtWidgets.QAction("Телефонные номера")
        self.action_search_options_2.setCheckable(True)
        self.action_search_options_3 = QtWidgets.QAction("Электронные почты и акк") 
        self.action_search_options_3.setCheckable(True)

        self.group_action_1 = QtWidgets.QActionGroup(self.sub_menu_options_search)

        self.group_action_1.addAction(self.action_search_options_1) # добавление в groupbox
        self.group_action_1.addAction(self.action_search_options_2)
        self.group_action_1.addAction(self.action_search_options_3)

        self.sub_menu_options_search.addAction(self.action_search_options_1) # добавление в вложенное
        self.sub_menu_options_search.addAction(self.action_search_options_2) # меню
        self.sub_menu_options_search.addAction(self.action_search_options_3)

        self.sub_menu_options.addMenu(self.sub_menu_options_search) # добавление в меню опции


        # добавляем отдельное меню в главное меню
        self.menu.addMenu(self.sub_menu_options)
        self.menu.addMenu(self.sub_menu_view)
        self.menu.addMenu(self.sub_menu_help)

        # датчики
        self.options_settings_status.triggered.connect(self.toggleMenu)

        # добавляем в окно
        self.setMenuBar(self.menu)

    def create_toolBar(self):
        self.toolBar = QtWidgets.QToolBar()

        self.action_back = QtWidgets.QAction("Вернуться назад")
        self.toolBar.addAction(self.action_back)

        self.addToolBar(self.toolBar)

    # функции для датчиков
    def toggleMenu(self, state):

        if state:
            self.statusBar().show()
        else:
            self.statusBar().hide()


    def clicked_button_1(self):         
        widget = self.centralWidget.layout().itemAt(0).widget()
        self.centralWidget.layout().removeWidget(widget)     
        widget.hide()
        self.window_1 = window_1.Page_find_numbers()                           
        self.action_back.triggered.connect(self.clicked_action_back)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.window_1)

    def clicked_action_back(self):      
        widget = self.centralWidget.layout().itemAt(0).widget()
        self.centralWidget.layout().removeWidget(widget)     
        widget.hide()
        self.widget_main = self.create_page()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.widget_main)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MainWindow() 
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

второй файл

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
import main
import re

class Page_find_numbers(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):

        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)

        # обьекты
        self.button_clear = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Очистить")    
        self.button_find = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Запустить")

        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Вставте сюда текст, в котором хотите\nнайти телефонные номера и электронные\nпочты.")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Результат:")

        self.textedit_1 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()

        self.textedit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.textedit_2.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.TextBrowserInteraction)

        self.gridbox = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        # добавление в box

        self.gridbox.addWidget(self.label_1, 0, 0)
        self.gridbox.addWidget(self.label_2, 2, 0)
        self.gridbox.addWidget(self.button_find, 0, 1)
        self.gridbox.addWidget(self.button_clear, 1, 1)
        self.gridbox.addWidget(self.textedit_1, 1, 0)
        self.gridbox.addWidget(self.textedit_2, 4, 0)

        self.gridbox.setVerticalSpacing(18)

        self.setLayout(self.gridbox)

        # датчики событий
        self.button_clear.clicked.connect(self.textedit_1.clear)
        self.button_clear.clicked.connect(self.textedit_2.clear)

        self.button_find.clicked.connect(self.to_seek_nomer_email)


    def to_seek_nomer_email(self):

        PlainText = self.textedit_1.toPlainText()

        # берём для проверки на установленность
        self.action_options_1 = main.MainWindow().action_search_options_1
        self.action_options_2 = main.MainWindow().action_search_options_2
        self.action_options_3 = main.MainWindow().action_search_options_3


        if len(PlainText) > 0: 

            # шаблон для телефонных номеров
            inserted_text_1 = re.compile(r'\W?\D?\d\s?\d\d\d\D?\s?\d\d\d\s?-?\d\d\s?-?\d\d')
            # акк и электронных почт
            email_akk = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,50}@[a-z]{2,6}\.[a-z]{2,4}')

            # собирает данные
            email_text = email_akk.findall(PlainText)
            telephon_text = inserted_text_1.findall(PlainText)

            # если в массиве оказались телефонные номера или акк и почты
            if len(email_text) > 0 or len(telephon_text) > 0:

                # проверка на установленный режим действия
                if self.action_options_1.isChecked() == True:            
                    text = "Телефонные номера:\n" + str(telephon_text) + "\n" +"Электронные почты:\n" + str(email_text)           
                    self.textedit_2.setText(text)

                if self.action_options_2.isChecked() == True:
                    text = "Телефонные номера:\n" + str(telephon_text)
                    self.textedit_2.setText(text)

                if self.action_options_3.isChecked() == True:
                    text = "Электронные почты:\n" + str(email_text)
                    self.textedit_2.setText(text)

            # если в списке нет номеров
            elif len(email_text) == 0 and len(telephon_text) == 0:
                self.textedit_2.setText("Данных не обнаружено")


        elif len(PlainText) == 0:
            self.textedit_2.setText("Введите данные!")



# ------ вставить текст в поле для поиска тел и акк ------
# щоашгомошвамшто (+5 555) 555 55 55 апрарdfb 89209103333 
# ваииапп 342423 пиа 8 888 888 88-88 dfbdfg gkfkvin@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
import window_1


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, action_search_options_1 = None, action_search_options_2 = None, 
                action_search_options_3 = None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        # берём из функции create_menuBar QAction для работы с файлом window_1
        self.action_search_options_1 = action_search_options_1
        self.action_search_options_2 = action_search_options_2
        self.action_search_options_3 = action_search_options_3

        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget() # создаём центральный виджет
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)

        # settings
        self.setFixedSize(640, 540)
        self.setWindowTitle(" B U G ")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("bug.ico"))

        # делаем сборку
        self.widget_main = self.create_page()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.widget_main)
        self.create_menuBar()
        self.create_toolBar()

    def create_page(self):
        self.widget_page = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        # создание обьектов
        self.button_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Перейти к поиску телефонных\nномеров и электронных почт")
        self.formbox = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        # добавление в box и в окно
        self.formbox.addWidget(self.button_1)
        self.formbox.setSpacing(20)
        self.widget_page.setLayout(self.formbox)
        # датчики и события
        self.button_1.clicked.connect(self.clicked_button_1)
        # сделать главным комонентом в общем
        return self.widget_page  # возращает

    def create_menuBar(self):
        # создание панели-меню и строки состоянии
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenuBar()
        self.status_1 = QtWidgets.QStatusBar()

        self.setStatusBar(self.status_1)
        self.status_1.showMessage("Добро пожаловать!", msecs = 5000)

        # создание категорий меню и функционал в ней
        self.sub_menu_options = QtWidgets.QMenu("Опции")
        self.sub_menu_view = QtWidgets.QMenu('Вид')
        self.sub_menu_help = QtWidgets.QMenu("Справка")

        self.sub_menu_in_options_settings_1 = QtWidgets.QMenu("Настройки")
        self.sub_menu_options_search = QtWidgets.QMenu("Настройки поиска")
        self.sub_menu_in_options_settings_3 = QtWidgets.QMenu("Настройки генерации")

        # настройки строки состояния
        self.options_settings_status = QtWidgets.QAction("Включить панель состояния")
        self.options_settings_status.setCheckable(True)
        self.options_settings_status.setChecked(True)

        self.sub_menu_in_options_settings_1.addAction(self.options_settings_status)
        self.sub_menu_options.addMenu(self.sub_menu_in_options_settings_1)

        # настройки поиска
        self.action_search_options_1 = QtWidgets.QAction("Искать всё")
        self.action_search_options_1.setCheckable(True)
        self.action_search_options_1.setChecked(True)
        self.action_search_options_2 = QtWidgets.QAction("Телефонные номера")
        self.action_search_options_2.setCheckable(True)
        self.action_search_options_3 = QtWidgets.QAction("Электронные почты и акк") 
        self.action_search_options_3.setCheckable(True)

        self.group_action_1 = QtWidgets.QActionGroup(self.sub_menu_options_search)

        self.group_action_1.addAction(self.action_search_options_1) # добавление в groupbox
        self.group_action_1.addAction(self.action_search_options_2)
        self.group_action_1.addAction(self.action_search_options_3)

        self.sub_menu_options_search.addAction(self.action_search_options_1) # добавление в вложенное
        self.sub_menu_options_search.addAction(self.action_search_options_2) # меню
        self.sub_menu_options_search.addAction(self.action_search_options_3)

        self.sub_menu_options.addMenu(self.sub_menu_options_search) # добавление в меню опции


        # добавляем отдельное меню в главное меню
        self.menu.addMenu(self.sub_menu_options)
        self.menu.addMenu(self.sub_menu_view)
        self.menu.addMenu(self.sub_menu_help)

        # датчики
        self.options_settings_status.triggered.connect(self.toggleMenu)

        # добавляем в окно
        self.setMenuBar(self.menu)

    def create_toolBar(self):
        self.toolBar = QtWidgets.QToolBar()

        self.action_back = QtWidgets.QAction("Вернуться назад")
        self.toolBar.addAction(self.action_back)

        self.addToolBar(self.toolBar)

    # функции для датчиков
    def toggleMenu(self, state):
        if state:
            self.statusBar().show()
        else:
            self.statusBar().hide()

    def clicked_button_1(self):         
        widget = self.centralWidget.layout().itemAt(0).widget()
        self.centralWidget.layout().removeWidget(widget)     
        widget.hide()

        self.window_1 = window_1.Page_find_numbers(self)                          # + self

        self.action_back.triggered.connect(self.clicked_action_back)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.window_1)

    def clicked_action_back(self):      
        widget = self.centralWidget.layout().itemAt(0).widget()
        self.centralWidget.layout().removeWidget(widget)     
        widget.hide()
        self.widget_main = self.create_page()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.widget_main)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MainWindow() 
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**window_1.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
# ? import main
import re

class Page_find_numbers(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
#        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        super().__init__(parent)                                               # .parent
        #print(parent)
        self.parent = parent                                                    # self.parent

        # обьекты
        self.button_clear = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Очистить")    
        self.button_find = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Запустить")

        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Вставте сюда текст, в котором хотите\nнайти телефонные номера и электронные\nпочты.")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel("Результат:")

        self.textedit_1 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()

        self.textedit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.textedit_2.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.TextBrowserInteraction)

        self.gridbox = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        # добавление в box

        self.gridbox.addWidget(self.label_1, 0, 0)
        self.gridbox.addWidget(self.label_2, 2, 0)
        self.gridbox.addWidget(self.button_find, 0, 1)
        self.gridbox.addWidget(self.button_clear, 1, 1)
        self.gridbox.addWidget(self.textedit_1, 1, 0)
        self.gridbox.addWidget(self.textedit_2, 4, 0)

        self.gridbox.setVerticalSpacing(18)

        self.setLayout(self.gridbox)

        # датчики событий
        self.button_clear.clicked.connect(self.textedit_1.clear)
        self.button_clear.clicked.connect(self.textedit_2.clear)

        self.button_find.clicked.connect(self.to_seek_nomer_email)


    def to_seek_nomer_email(self):

        PlainText = self.textedit_1.toPlainText()

        # берём для проверки на установленность
#        self.action_options_1 = main.MainWindow().action_search_options_1
#        self.action_options_2 = main.MainWindow().action_search_options_2
#        self.action_options_3 = main.MainWindow().action_search_options_3
        self.action_options_1 = self.parent.action_search_options_1            # self.parent
        self.action_options_2 = self.parent.action_search_options_2            # self.parent
        self.action_options_3 = self.parent.action_search_options_3            # self.parent


        if len(PlainText) > 0: 

            # шаблон для телефонных номеров
            inserted_text_1 = re.compile(r'\W?\D?\d\s?\d\d\d\D?\s?\d\d\d\s?-?\d\d\s?-?\d\d')
            # акк и электронных почт
            email_akk = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,50}@[a-z]{2,6}\.[a-z]{2,4}')

            # собирает данные
            email_text = email_akk.findall(PlainText)
            telephon_text = inserted_text_1.findall(PlainText)

            # если в массиве оказались телефонные номера или акк и почты
            if len(email_text) > 0 or len(telephon_text) > 0:

                # проверка на установленный режим действия
                if self.action_options_1.isChecked() == True:            
                    text = "Телефонные номера:\n" + str(telephon_text) + "\n" +"Электронные почты:\n" + str(email_text)           
                    self.textedit_2.setText(text)

                if self.action_options_2.isChecked() == True:
                    text = "Телефонные номера:\n" + str(telephon_text)
                    self.textedit_2.setText(text)

                if self.action_options_3.isChecked() == True:
                    text = "Электронные почты:\n" + str(email_text)
                    self.textedit_2.setText(text)

            # если в списке нет номеров
            elif len(email_text) == 0 and len(telephon_text) == 0:
                self.textedit_2.setText("Данных не обнаружено")


        elif len(PlainText) == 0:
            self.textedit_2.setText("Введите данные!")



# ------ вставить текст в поле для поиска тел и акк ------
# щоашгомошвамшто (+5 555) 555 55 55 апрарdfb 89209103333 
# ваииапп 342423 пиа 8 888 888 88-88 dfbdfg gkfkvin@gmail.com
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]